# Como fazer vários registros de checkbox no banco de dados de uma só vez?

Tags: php, mysql

Como faço múltiplos registros com `checkbox`?

Preciso fazer múltiplos registros de acordo com a minha marcação em cada `checkbox` e incluir na coluna `id_item` o mesmo `ID` que vem da variável  `$proximoID` em todos os registros.

Estou tentando isso, só que não está funcionando:

```
<form action="#" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Flights on: <br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="categoria[]" value="1">segunda<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="categoria[]" value="2">Sunday<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="categoria[]" value="3">Monday<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="categoria[]" value="4">Tuesday <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="categoria[]" value="5">Wednesday<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="categoria[]" value="6">Thursday <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="categoria[]" value="7">Friday<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="categoria[]" value="8">Saturday <br>
<input type="submit" name="insert" value="submit">
</form>

  if(isset($_POST['insert']))
  {

    $checkBox = $_POST['categoria'];

                    for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($checkBox); $i++) {
                    $cadastrarItem = $DB->prepare("INSERT INTO teste (id_item, id_category) VALUES ($proximoID, '" . $checkBox[$i] . "')");
          }
            $cadastrarItem->execute();

                    if($cadastrarItem->rowCount() >= 0)
                    {
                        echo 'sucesso';
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo 'erro';
                    }

  }
```

/

```
/ ESSE CÓDIGO É PARA PEGAR O ID DO ITEM, POR EXEMPLO A VARIAVEL $proximoID VAI DAR UM NUMERO, EU PRECISO QUE ESSE NUMERO ESTEJA NOS MULTIPLOS REGISTRO E ALTERE APENAS O id DO $checkBox
      try {
      $sql = "SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'teste' ";
      $stmt = $DB->prepare($sql);
      $stmt->execute();
      $resultado = $stmt->fetch();
      $proximoID = $resultado['Auto_increment'];  // a chave esta aqui
       } catch (Exception $ex) {
       echo $ex->getMessage();
      }

      echo $proximoID;
```

@edit

```
$checkBox = array_filter($_POST['categoria'], 'is_int');
// Segurança: apenas haverá números inteiros, dessa forma se houver: (1,2,3,biscoito,5,10,lasanha) irá ser: (1,2,3,5,10)

$sqlParcial = '';

for ($i=0; $i < count($checkBox); $i++) {
$sqlParcial .= '("'. $checkBox[$i] .'", (SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name = "teste" AND table_schema = DATABASE()) -'. $i .'),';
}

$cadastrarItem = $DB->prepare("INSERT INTO teste (id_category, id_item) VALUES ". $sqlParcial."");
$cadastrarItem->execute();

if($cadastrarItem->rowCount() >= 0)
{
    echo 'sucesso';
}
  else
{
  echo 'erro';
}
```

Comment: Você quer inserir IDs repetidos numa coluna de _auto increment_?

Comment: @Bacco Não, quero inserir os ids repetidos apenas na coluna 'id_item'

Comment: Talvez fosse melhor abandonar o código de pegar o ID, e pegar no primeiro INSERT então. Teoricamente o id_item do 1o item corresponderia ao seu auto_increment. Aí no primeiro deles teria que dar um UPDATE, mas é mais seguro do que pegar o item antes;

Comment: @Bacco Não coloquei no insert a coluna do ID auto increment..

Comment: Isso eu entendi, mas vc ta pegando ele como ID inicial, e copiando nos id_item, certo? Outra coisa, você pode concatenar os VALUES e fazer um insert só mesmo. (repetindo os pares dentro de VALUES( ) )

Comment: @Bacco Não, tipo eu tenho 500 registros em uma tabela, essa outra tabela 'teste' que está no codigo, vai separar os 500 registros em determinada categoria

Comment: Ah bom. É que nos dois códigos a tabela é "teste", por isso eu achei estranho.

Comment: Nesssa tabela 'teste' tem 3 coluna, id, id_item, id_category, o id é auto increment, o id_item é id auto increment dos posts de otura tabela, e o id_category é os value do HTML que está no código

Comment: O `$proximoID` é igual ao `$idItem`?

Comment: @Inkeliz Sim, esqueci de apagar

Comment: @Inkeliz Pronto, editei o post

Comment: É inserido alguma coisa na tabela `teste`?

Comment: @Inkeliz Tipo, quando eu coloquei apenas 1 coluna, funcionou, ai eu coloquei as 2 coluna e só envia 1 registro sendo q eu selecionava 3 checkbox

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> O exemplo será feito em MySQLi, caso use (como parece) o PDO será necessário fazer algumas adaptações, irei acrescentar comentários com funções equivalentes, mas não garanto funcionamento, pois nunca usei PDO na prática.

Existem vários métodos, irei listar um deles:

```
<?
if(isset($_POST['insert'])){
$checkBox = array_filter($_POST['categoria'], 'ctype_digit');
// Segurança: apenas haverá números inteiros, dessa forma se houver: (1,2,3,biscoito,5,10,lasanha) irá ser: (1,2,3,5,10)

$sqlParcial = '';
// Remover o Warning

for ($i=0; $i < count($checkBox); $i++) {

$sqlParcial .= '("'. $checkBox[$i] .'", (SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name = "teste" AND table_schema = DATABASE()) -'. $i .'),';
// O "- $i" era subtrair o AUTO_INCRMENT pelo o número da postagem, assim igualando com o número da primeira.
// O (SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name = 'teste' AND table_schema = DATABASE()) irá pegar o AUTO_INCREMENT!
// O sqlParcial irá armazenar tudo um do lado do outro exemplo: $sqlParcial será (1, 0),(2, 0),(5, 0), EXEMPLO!

}


$sqlParcial =  trim($sqlParcial, ",");
// Irá remover a ultima virgula

# MySQLi:
if($mysqli->query('INSERT INTO teste (id_category, id_item) VALUES '. $sqlParcial)){
echo 'sucesso'; 
}

# PDO:
if($pdo->exec('INSERT INTO teste (id_category, id_item) VALUES '. $sqlParcial)){
echo 'sucesso'; 
}

// Faz o query adicionando o trecho do MySQL definido lá no inicio.
// Irá executar por exemplo: INSERT INTO teste (id_category, id_item) VALUES (1, 0),(2, 0),(5, 0) EXEMPLO!
}
?>
```

Isso supre ambas as funções que disse.
Com somente este código irá inserir multiplos dados e obter o id (AUTO_INCREMENT) em um só código.

Acredito que isso é um dos melhores e mais compactos métodos que pode fazer. Existe um problema de Race Condition, entretanto devido à query agir rapidamente acredito que não chega a ocorrer problema.

> Tentei inserir o máximo de detalhes possíveis para que não haja duvidas e entenda o processo.

### Testes:

**PHP:**

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'senha');
$mysqli->select_db('db');

if(isset($_POST['insert'])){

$checkBox = array_filter($_POST['categoria'], 'ctype_digit');
// Segurança: apenas haverá números inteiros, dessa forma se houver: (1,2,3,biscoito,5,10,lasanha) irá ser: (1,2,3,5,10)

$sqlParcial = '';
// Remover o Warning

for($i=0; $i < count($checkBox); $i++){

$sqlParcial .= '("'. $checkBox[$i] .'", (SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name = "teste" AND table_schema = DATABASE()) -'. $i .'),';
// O "- $i" era subtrair o AUTO_INCRMENT pelo o número da postagem, assim igualando com o número da primeira.
// O (SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name = 'teste' AND table_schema = DATABASE()) irá pegar o AUTO_INCREMENT!
// O sqlParcial irá armazenar tudo um do lado do outro exemplo: $sqlParcial será (1, 0),(2, 0),(5, 0), EXEMPLO!

}


$sqlParcial =  trim($sqlParcial, ",");
// Irá remover a ultima virgula

# MySQLi:
if($mysqli->query('INSERT INTO teste (id_category, id_item) VALUES '. $sqlParcial)){
echo 'sucesso'; 
}

// Faz o query adicionando o trecho do MySQL definido lá no inicio.
// Irá executar por exemplo: INSERT INTO teste (id_category, id_item) VALUES (1, 0),(2, 0),(5, 0) EXEMPLO!
}
?>
<form action="#" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Flights on: <br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="categoria[]" value="1">segunda<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="categoria[]" value="2">Sunday<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="categoria[]" value="3">Monday<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="categoria[]" value="4">Tuesday <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="categoria[]" value="5">Wednesday<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="categoria[]" value="6">Thursday <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="categoria[]" value="7">Friday<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="categoria[]" value="8">Saturday <br>
<input type="submit" name="insert" value="submit">
</form>
```

**MySQL:**

```
--
-- Tabela
--

CREATE TABLE `teste` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_item` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_category` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dados iniciais
--

INSERT INTO `teste` (`id`, `id_item`, `id_category`) VALUES
(20, 0, 0);

--
-- Index para id
--
ALTER TABLE `teste`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT inicial
--
ALTER TABLE `teste`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=21;
```

**Resultado:**

Selecionando:

segunda
Sunday
Monday

Insere:

```
ID | id_item |  id_category   
21 | 21      | 1   
22 | 21      | 2  
23 | 21      | 3
```

Comment: Ta selecionando auto_increment de onde ali ?

Comment: Não funcionou, Notice: Undefined variable: sqlParcial in C:\xampp\htdocs\carregamento_dinamico\teste.php on line 48

Comment: Ta invertido ai, primeiro vem id_item, id_category

Comment: O auto_increment está selecionado em `(SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name = 'teste' AND table_schema = DATABASE())`, é subtraido do `$i`. Então, se for 10. O primeiro valor será `10 - 0 = 10`, o segundo `11-1 = 10`, depois `12-2 = 10`. Todos serão `10`. Acredito que não esteja invertido. O primeiro valor é do `id_category` e o segundo é do `id_item`. O INSERT não necessariamente deve seguir a ordem das tabelas, mas os `VALUES` devem seguir a ordem do `INSERT INTO`. Fiz uma mudança para remover o `Notice`.

Comment: O código não insere no banco de dados. e não apareceu nenhum erro.

Comment: Editei o post, com o código que vc me passou..

Comment: Acho que corrigi o problema.

Comment: Muito obrigado :D Quase consegui, com implode

Comment: O `implode` também poderia resolver. Na verdade acabo por esquecer de utilizar ele, mas caso queria pode usar também, acredito que até pode facilitar minimamente a leitura. Quanto a performance (entre este método e o implode) acredito que a diferença seria minima para se preocupar.