# Obter estado do item JSON do CS:GO

Tags: php, javascript, json

Bom é o seguinte eu tenho o seguinte código que faz com que pegue todos os itens/armas do inventário de um determinado individuo e mostra-o.

Bom o que eu queria saber é como faço para além de pegar os itens dizer o estado do item, do tipo:

Sawed-Off | Full Stop (Field-Tested)

Meu Código:

```
<?php
$steamid = '76561198103888786';

$destUrl = 'http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/' . $steamid . '/inventory/json/730/2/';

$data = file_get_contents($destUrl, false);
$data = json_decode($data, true);
$data1= array_keys($data['rgDescriptions']);
$data2= $data['rgDescriptions'];
for($i = 0; $i < count($data1); ++$i) {
    $items =  $data2[$data1[$i]]['name'];
        echo $items;
        echo "<br>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

O item em questão mencionado de exemplo é o `310778159_302028390`.

[image: CS:GO API]

Dessa forma, deve apenas obter o `market_hash_name` ou o `market_name` ao invés do `name`.

Neste caso basta inserir:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($data1); ++$i) {

    echo '<br> ID: '. $data1[$i];
    echo '<br> Name: '. $data2[$data1[$i]]['name'];
    echo '<br> Market_Hash_Name: '. $data2[$data1[$i]]['market_hash_name'];
    echo '<br> Market_Name: '. $data2[$data1[$i]]['market_name'];
    echo '<br>';

}
```

Com isso irá obter e exibir todos os dados, tanto dos `market_*` tanto o do `name`.

Comment: Consegui perfeitamente obter todos os itens, agora no caso como faria para colocar cada item em 1 variavel no caso, $item1 = primeiro item, $item2 = segundo item, $item3 = terceiro item, como poderei fazer isso, para que consiga inserir todos os itens do jogador no bd.?

Comment: Existem várias e várias formas. Eu, hoje, iria fazer assim: `$inventario[] = "(0, $usuario, $name, $market_hash, $market_name)"`, dentro do `for`. Depois iria fazer um `$valores = implode(',', $inventario)`. Dessa forma bastaria fazer um `INSERT INTO tabela VALUES $valores`. Em teste iria ficar: `INSERT INTO tabela VALUES (0,1,2,3,4), (0,1,7,8,9), (0,1,3,4,5)`, por exemplo. Respondi uma questão parecida, sem usar o `implode`, mas com mesma ideia em http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/112798/como-fazer-v%C3%A1rios-registros-de-checkbox-no-banco-de-dados-de-uma-s%C3%B3-vez/112809#112809.

Comment: Pode editar a sua resposta com isso para ficar mais organizado? Obrigado.